# aws ses.sendEmail is not being called from lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My lambda function written in node.js is quite simple.
Lambda is called when new entry appear in dynamo db, then I want to loop through each entry and send an email. For some reason I can't understand why ses.SendEmail function is never called. I placed logs inside it but nothing appear in logs. I obfuscated email just for the purpose of the question (I am using actual correct email on aws).

```
console.log('Loading function');
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new aws.SES({region: 'eu-west-2'});
//var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    //console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    event.Records.forEach((record) => {
        if(record.eventName == 'INSERT')
        {
            console.log(record.eventID);
            console.log(record.eventName);
            console.log('DynamoDB Record: %j', record.dynamodb);
            
            var params = {
            Destination: {
                ToAddresses: ["test@***.com"]
            },
            Message: {
                Body: {
                    Text: { Data: "Test"
                        
                    }
                    
                },
                
                Subject: { Data: "Test Email"
                    
                }
            },
            Source: "info@***.com"
        };
        
        console.log("About to send email");
            ses.sendEmail(params, function (err, data) {
            
            console.log("inside email"); // not logging
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                context.fail(err);
            } else {
                
                console.log(data);
                context.succeed(event);
            }
        });
        }
    });
    
    //return `Successfully processed ${event.Records.length} records.`;
    
};
```

Comment: Don't mix and match async and callbacks, choose one or the other. Assuming your loop is in fact being executed (e.g. `console.log("About to send email");` prints), try something like this: `await ses.sendEmail(params).promise();` rather than that callback. And you don't need to use `context` either, as that will throw an exception if there's an error, and the function will fail. Just noticed you're also doing it in a non async forEach loop, you might need to restructure that to use await.

Comment: Thank you, I merged my send email lambda with template for dynamo trigger, hence it was async. Works as expected now, appreciate your help.