# aws ses.sendEmail working from local but not remote

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a node.js function that is supposed to send an email.  When I run the script locally using NODE REPL it works fine and I get the email as expected.  However, when I deploy it to AWS I do not get any emails.

I did see this result with a similar title: [aws ses.sendEmail is not being called from lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63632550/aws-ses-sendemail-is-not-being-called-from-lambda-function), however, that was using async which I am not.

```
let aws = require('aws-sdk'),
        ses = new aws.SES({ region: 'us-east-1' }),
        makeParams = request => {
            console.log('send' + request)
            // console.log('markparam: '+request)
            var emailBody = 'BOO bOO BAR';
            // console.log(request.body)
            for (var a in request.body) {
                // console.log(a);
                // emailBody +=' test'
                // console.log(request.body[a]);
                // emailBody += `${a}: ${request.body[a]}<br />`
            }

            return {
                Destination: { /* required */
                    ToAddresses: [
                        creators@xxxxxxxx.com
                    ]
                },
                Message: { /* required */
                    Body: { /* required */
                        Html: {
                            Data: emailBody, /* required */
                            Charset: 'UTF-8'
                        },
                        Text: {
                            // Data: emailBody.replace(/<br \/>/, "\r\n"), /* required */
                            Data: emailBody,
                            Charset: 'UTF-8'
                        }
                    },
                    Subject: { /* required */
                        Data: 'New Opportunity Submitted', /* required */
                        Charset: 'UTF-8'
                    }
                },
                Source: 'creators@xxxxxxxx.org'
                
            }
        },
        send = request => {
            console.log('send request: '+request.body)
            return ses.sendEmail(makeParams(request)).promise().then(function(data){
                console.log('data: '+data)
            }).catch(function(err){console.log('error: '+ err,err.stack)});
        };

When I run it locally using NODE this is my output:
```

```
Welcome to Node.js v14.17.6.
Type ".help" for more information.
> let b = require('./app/bindings.js')
undefined
> b.send({body: {foo:'bar',bar:'baz'}})
send request: [object Object]
send[object Object]
Promise { <pending> }
> data: [object Object]
> .exit
```

Here you can see that it prints the data after sending the email which confirms to me that it sends.

However, if I try to do it remotely either from my web app, or using CURL as:

```
curl -X POST -d '{body: { foo:"bar",bar:"baz" }}' https://xxxxx4d.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/latest/new-opportunity/
```

This results in a cloudwatch log like:

```
2022-01-13T16:27:50.649-05:00   START RequestId: b7611af9-2b5a-4d29-a59f-ad074683982f Version: $LATEST

2022-01-13T16:27:50.653-05:00   2022-01-13T21:27:50.653Z b7611af9-2b5a-4d29-a59f-ad074683982f INFO request[object Object]

2022-01-13T16:27:50.653-05:00   2022-01-13T21:27:50.653Z b7611af9-2b5a-4d29-a59f-ad074683982f INFO send request: undefined

2022-01-13T16:27:50.673-05:00   2022-01-13T21:27:50.673Z b7611af9-2b5a-4d29-a59f-ad074683982f INFO send{body:{foo:'bar',bat:'baz'}}

2022-01-13T16:27:51.076-05:00   END RequestId: b7611af9-2b5a-4d29-a59f-ad074683982f
```

It does not seem to hit the send.  It is the same code with no changes, but I am at a loss for why it will send an email when run locally vs remotely.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem and solution was further back.  Inside my `index.js` I have the actual API call which is:

`api.post('/new-opportunity', request => {console.log('request: '+request); bindings.send(request)});`

When I remove the console.log and I am left with this:

`api.post('/new-opportunity', request => bindings.send(request));`

It works like a charm.  I am not sure, why it was the console.log, any insight for me and future readers would be appreciated.